# Slider Revolution 5.3.1: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'cssText')

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, revolution-slider

I have this problem with a wordpress website using a hard-coded slider revolution plugin v5.3.1 + acf combo where the slider doesn't load and I keep getting a console error which says:

```
VM192 jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:104 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'cssText')
at VM192 jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:104:1873
at Function.<anonymous> (VM192 jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:104:1931)
at q.check (VM192 jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60:822)
at new q (VM192 jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60:1176)
at a._gsDefine (VM192 jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60:1226)
at VM192 jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:104:187
at VM192 jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:105:8674
```

The wordpress version is updated to ver. 5.9.1 and I downgraded the jQuery version is to 1.12.4.

The site is https://woodlandsvalencia.com/

This is the Slider + ACF code used:

```
<ul>
                            <?php
                            $cnt = 0;
                            if(get_field('home_banner', '2')) {
                            while(the_repeater_field('home_banner', '2')){
                            $bannerimage = get_sub_field('banner_image', '2');
                            $bannertitle = get_sub_field('banner_title', '2');
                            $bannertext = get_sub_field('banner_text', '2');
                            $bannerbuttontext = get_sub_field('banner_button_text', '2');
                            $bannerbuttonlink = get_sub_field('banner_button_link', '2');
                            $cnt++;
                            ?>
                        
                        <li data-index="rs-<?=$cnt?>" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="default" data-hideafterloop="0" data-hideslideonmobile="off" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300" data-thumb="#" data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Slide" data-param1="" data-param2="" data-param3="" data-param4="" data-param5="" data-param6="" data-param7="" data-param8="" data-param9="" data-param10="" data-description="">
                                <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme" id="slide-1-layer-9" data-x="135" data-y="" data-width="['none','none','none','none']" data-height="['none','none','none','none']" data-type="image" data-responsive_offset="on" data-frames='[{"delay":10,"speed":600,"frame":"0","from":"opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"opacity:0;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]' data-textAlign="['inherit','inherit','inherit','inherit']" data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]" style="z-index: 5;"><img src="<?=$bannerimage?>" alt="" data-ww="1410px" data-hh="948px" width="1410" height="948" data-no-retina>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme" id="slide-1-layer-1" data-x="40" data-y="280" data-width="['auto']" data-height="['auto']" data-type="text" data-responsive_offset="on" data-frames='[{"delay":100,"speed":800,"frame":"0","from":"opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"opacity:0;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]' data-textAlign="['inherit','inherit','inherit','inherit']" data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]" style="z-index: 6; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 80px; line-height: 80px; font-weight: 100; color: rgba(141, 110, 92, 1.00);font-family:Raleway;">
                                    <?= $bannertitle?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme" id="slide-1-layer-2" data-x="40" data-y="380" data-width="['auto']" data-height="['auto']" data-type="text" data-responsive_offset="on" data-frames='[{"delay":150,"speed":800,"frame":"0","from":"opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"opacity:0;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]' data-textAlign="['inherit','inherit','inherit','inherit']" data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]" style="z-index: 7; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 70px; line-height: 68px; font-weight: 400; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);font-family:Raleway;">
                                    <?=$bannertext?>
                                </div>
                                <a class="tp-caption rev-btn  tp-resizeme" href="<?php bloginfo('home') ?>/<?=$bannerbuttonlink?>" target="_self" id="slide-1-layer-4" data-x="40" data-y="550" data-width="['auto']" data-height="['auto']" data-type="button" data-actions='' data-responsive_offset="on" data-frames='[{"delay":200,"speed":800,"frame":"0","from":"opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"opacity:0;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"frame":"hover","speed":"300","ease":"Linear.easeNone","to":"o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;","style":"c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bg:rgba(113, 81, 64, 1.00);bs:solid;bw:0 0 0 0;"}]' data-textAlign="['inherit','inherit','inherit','inherit']" data-paddingtop="[15,15,15,15]" data-paddingright="[32,32,32,32]" data-paddingbottom="[15,15,15,15]" data-paddingleft="[32,32,32,32]" style="z-index: 8; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; font-weight: 700; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);font-family:Playfair Display;background-color:rgba(141, 110, 92, 1.00);border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);outline:none;box-shadow:none;box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;"><?=$bannerbuttontext?></a>
                                <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme" id="slide-1-layer-7" data-x="100" data-y="" data-width="['none','none','none','none']" data-height="['none','none','none','none']" data-type="image" data-responsive_offset="on" data-frames='[{"delay":250,"speed":800,"frame":"0","from":"y:-50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"opacity:0;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]' data-textAlign="['inherit','inherit','inherit','inherit']" data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]" style="z-index: 9;"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/home_shoes_slider_sep.png" alt="" data-ww="1px" data-hh="263px" width="1" height="263" data-no-retina>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            
                            <?php } } ?>
                            
                        </ul>
```

Has anybody experienced this type of issue? May I know how you resolved it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix the issue by downgrading the CSS PLUGIN version from version 1.19.0 to 1.18.0.

This may not be the best solution but since the revolution slider implementation was hard-coded and using the old versions on a custom WordPress site, this was the way to go.

I hope this would help someone in need.